# Notify Spotify of hackathon usage

Tags: spotify

I am hosting a hackathon at my company and intending on making use of the Spotify WebAPI. I wanted to know what the preferred way of registering apps (does every attendee need a Spotify account or is there some work I can do ahead of the hackathon to have everything ready), as well as notify Spotify of a period of time they can expect a high volume of requests originating from my company's IP.

My planned approach is to have 1 premium account with multiple apps registered (1 per team). Is there a better way to do this?